# Is it possible to do a dual boot for Acer Iconia W700?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, acer, tablet

I'm afraid to do this on my own, because this is my daily driver. Anyone have any instructions of a video that could guide me. Help!!! Windows is killing me....

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question: http://community.acer.com/t5/Windows-Tablets/Linux-on-W700/td-p/47489

If not just tell me.